# Are there any issues with using a this.variable as an argument default in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, es6-class

If I have an ES6 class like:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }
  echo(value=this.bar) {
    return value;
  }
}
```

`this.bar` should be re-evaluated each time `echo` is called.

```
f = new Foo(10);
f.echo();
>> 10
f.bar = 99;
f.echo();
>> 99
```

Are there any potential issues that could come from this usage?

Comment: What output were you expecting ?

Comment: The default argument scope thing is crazy

Comment: It's doing what I expect, I'm just wondering if this is bad practice or could lead to some unforeseen consequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there is nothing BIG to be concerned of, except the usual js `this` problem.
You can inject values into this method using the call, bind, etc method.
This could also cause errors and inconsistencies.

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }
  echo(value=this.bar) {
    return value;
  }
}

f = new Foo(10);
console.log('f', f.echo().toFixed(0))
console.log('f', f.echo.call({bar: 50}).toFixed(0))

try{
  console.log('f', f.echo.call(window).toFixed(0))
}catch(e){
  console.error(e);
}


class Fooo {
  constructor(bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
    // fixing the scope
    this.echo = (value=this.bar) => {
      return value;
    }
  }
}


f2 = new Fooo(10);
console.log('f2', f2.echo().toFixed(0))
console.log('f2', f2.echo.call({bar: 50}).toFixed(0))

try{
  console.log('f2', f2.echo.call(window).toFixed(0))
}catch(e){
  console.error(e);
}
```

Comment: Are proxy objects really that big of a problem *here*? If somebody is in a position to supply proxies to OP's code, the `this.bar` is hardly the only vector of attack. Absolutely everything would be vulnerable and the attacker can likely just write a straight infinite loop anyway, without needing to ever construct a proxy. So, it's like saying that if somebody broke into your home, they could steal all your pennies lying around. While true, that's not the biggest problem you have.

Comment: Of cause there is a lot to attack in this case. But with proxies you might even bypass read only and frozen properties defined by `Object.defineProperty()`. I just wanted to show, what also code execution in the objects scope in general is possible in this case. The DoS attack was just a example :)

Comment: And I don't think it's really relevant to bring up. Pretty much *every* code is vulnerable. An attacker can overwrite the `.sort()` method but I see no reason in bringing it up on a question on sorting arrays. And, again, if an attacker can do *that*, protecting against a malicious `.sort()` method is the least of your worries. Similarly here if an attacker is supplying you with malicious proxies should be near the bottom of the priority list - the attacker would already be able to write `for(;;)` instead of `new Proxy()`. Protecting only against the latter doesn't have a lot of value.

Comment: Well ok. I removed it ;)

Answer (score 2):

It's technically correct, but it better to reduce scope as much as possible. The overuse of global (this) variables can lead to messy or hard-to-read code aka `spaghetti code`.

Answer (score 1):

Well..

`echo(value=this.bar)` will set `value` to `this.bar` if `value === undefined` as pointed out in the comments. So you are doing: `value = value === undefined ? this.bar : value;`

It`s basically the same thing as doing:

```
class Foo {
  constructor(bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
  }
  echo(value) {
    let value = value === undefined ? this.bar : value;
    return value;
  }
}
```

If thats what you want - it's perfectly fine.

Comment: That is not true. `echo(value=this.bar)` will set `value` to `this.bar` if `value === undefined`. its more like: `value = value === undefined ? this.bar : value;`

Comment: @Bellian well in this particular case  (without seeing more code) it would always be undefined. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You are. Value can be set on function call. (echo('hello world')) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters

Comment: @Bellian thank you for pointing it out, I have edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

It appears the [default param is evaluated at call time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Evaluated_at_call_time), so as long as **this** hasn't been bound by .bind(), .call(), or .apply(), it will always refer to the [object it's called on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method) when used within a method

I don't see any issues, unless you were to extend `Foo`, and call `echo` on a child object which also has `bar` property